# Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ implies $\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt L$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, radicals, epsilon-delta

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L>0.$  Prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{L}$.

I know that we have:

$$\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{L}\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)-L}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}}\right|<\left|\frac{f(x)-L}{L}\right|<|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\text{.}$$

---

*Proof:* Given $\varepsilon>0$.  Let $\delta=\varepsilon$.  Assume $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L>0$.  So there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$\text{if }\; 0<|x-a|<\delta=\varepsilon\text{, then }\;|f(x)-L|<\delta=\varepsilon\text{.}$$

So, If $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then

$$\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{L}\right|=\frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}}\le \frac{|f(x)-L|}{L}<|f(x)-L|<\delta=\varepsilon\text{.}$$

Right or am I wrong?

Comment: Well you have an issue in the last steps in inequality. You can't have $$|(f(x)-L)/\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}|\le|(f(x)-L)/L|<|(f(x)-L)|<\epsilon$$ but rather you should write $$\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{L}|=|(f(x)-L)/\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}|\le|(f(x)-L)/\sqrt{L}|< \epsilon /\sqrt{L}$$

Comment: And I don't see how you can put $\delta = \epsilon$. Note that in definition of limits $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily given and $\delta$ is dependent on $\epsilon$ but unless you know more about the function you can't say exactly how $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. So putting $\delta = \epsilon$ is wrong here and I don't understand what purpose does it have in your argument.

Comment: See also this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517411/fx-has-a-limit-prove-that-sqrtfx-has-a-limit

Comment: You can't really state $\displaystyle \frac{|f(x)-L|}{L}<|f(x)-L|$ or $\displaystyle\frac{|f(x)-L|}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{L}}\le \frac{|f(x)-L|}{L}$ unless you have certainty that $L>1$. This is a proof for the case $L>1$ but for $0<L\leq 1$ (not much) more work is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help to use different variables.

Since $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L > 0$, we know that:

> $\forall \varepsilon_1 > 0$, $\exists \delta_1 > 0$ such that if $0 < |x - a| < \delta_1$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon_1$

Now given any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\delta > 0$ be the $\delta_1$ corresponding to taking $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon\sqrt{L}$. Then observe that if $0 < |x - a| < \delta = \delta_1$, then:
\begin{align*}
\left|\sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{L} \right| &= \left|\frac{f(x) - L}{\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}}\right| \\
&= \frac{|f(x) - L|}{\sqrt{f(x)} + \sqrt{L}} \\
&\leq \frac{|f(x) - L|}{\sqrt{L}} \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon\sqrt{L}}{\sqrt{L}} \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align*}
Hence, it follows that $\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{L}$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$